# Short story with audible computer networks

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi, computers, communication

I am looking for a short story where all the computer to computer communications were audible to humans. After being exposed to this for long enough the younger generations start creating music similar to the sounds of the computers and later begin to intuitively understand and speak the same protocol as the computers.

It may have been set in the asteroid belt. If I'm not mixing my old stories, plans for inter asteroid travel were encoded on audio tapes for playback and execution by the ships autopilot.

I read it in some sort of anthology of best sci fi stories, probably from the 70s-80s, about 15 years ago and haven't been able to find it since.